# Fetch data less than a score in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, instagram, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to make an Instagram like Explore page using Elasticsearch. The contents are scored based on time as well as number of likes. Since, the content likes are frequently updated, pagination is difficult using From/Size and Search After. Suppose, I fetched first 10 posts using From 0, Size 10. Another 10 posts scored more likes by the time I'm trying to fetch the second page in pagination. Now, I have the same posts that I fetched in first pagination at positions 10 to 20. This will create lot of duplicate in my explore page.

I am more concerned about avoiding duplicates in pagination than missing some content, because if the user refresh explore page, the top contents will be displayed again. The best way I think is to fetch all posts below a particular score. Is there anything like a max_score api. If not, how can i solve this problem?